# What is the benefit of adding control flow to probabilistic programming?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, probabilistic-programming

I was watching an interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLFJ5ERxt2c) on the `Pyro` package in `Pytorch` for probabilistic programming. One of the things that they were promoting was the ability to add control flow, or "if-then" statements in their probabilistic models.

They gave an example where

$$
p \sim \text{Identity Matrix} \\
c \sim Categorical(p) \\
\text{if c > 0:} \\
\text{then d} \sim Normal(c-1, 10.0)
$$

Sorry for the formatting of the model/code. The point here is this conditional logic.

Now I understand that Graphical models don't usually have these types of loops. But I was not really clear on what happens when we introduce loops like this if/then statement, where if a certain category is chosen then the distribution of $d$ is something related to only those selected categories? Couldn't this be represented as just an edge between the categories $c >0$ and $d$, while the remaining categories had no edge.

Any examples or intuition behind this idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Look for Bayesian Networks (Not to be confused with Bayesian Neural Networks) and Markov Chains/Models they both address what you are talking about, but in different ways.

Comment: @SkanderH. I understand what you mean by Bayesian Networks and Markov Chains, but those don't have conditional logic in them. That is what was confusing me. Usually for a Bayesian network or directed/undirected PGM we would have some data and then an inference algorithm. I am not clear what having the conditional logic adds to the model. I am sure the conditional logic does add some flexibility, but I just was not sure what it is adding.

Comment: Hmmm -  I might have mispoke about Bayesian Networks. But there is definitely a version of Markov Chains that has additional conditional logic in it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process

Comment: @SkanderH. yep, I usually hear of Markov decision processes (MDP) in the context of reinforcement learning. But even there the logic is not conditional in the if-then sense. I think that the has a markov structure, so basically the probability distribution over the current decision is dependent on the immediately previous decision. But thanks for reminding me about MDPs as they definitely have a connection to Graphical Models.